# Gyroscope for DIY turtlebot

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm gathering the parts to build a turtlebot.  I have a question about the gyroscope that's use on it though.  I already have a board with a gyroscope on it from another project.  The gyro I have talks through I2C.  Would it be easy to use this one or should I just buy the same board that everyone else uses?

I'm just starting out so I'm not even sure where to find the code for the turtlebot that processes the gyro data.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52065/gyroscope-for-diy-turtlebot/) by [jd](https://answers.ros.org/users/2939/jd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2013-01-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jd](https://answers.ros.org/users/2939/jd/) on 2013-01-12**:
Looks like the Turtlebot uses an analog gyroscope (from JonW's links)?  Unfortunately, my gyro is digital but it should be easy just to add any analog one to the create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi jd,

There are two earlier answers that appear relevant to your query:

[This](http://answers.ros.org/question/9749/is-an-imu-required-to-run-turtlebot-stack/#1243) answer discusses the attachment of an analog gyro to an iRobot create base.

[This](http://answers.ros.org/question/12745/gyro-for-turtlebot/) answer discusses the availability of alternative analogue gyro sensors.

---

Originally posted by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) with karma: 586 on 2013-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1